# Como usar uma variável para fazer delete com like? SQL Server

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server, variáveis

Estou com problemas para desenvolver o T-SQL abaixo:

```
DECLARE @NOME_FILIAL VARCHAR(25); DECLARE @DATA_AJUSTE DATETIME;

SET @NOME_FILIAL = (SELECT FILIAL FROM FILIAIS WHERE COD_FILIAL='125518');

SET @DATA_AJUSTE = (SELECT DATA_AJUSTE FROM ESTOQUE_PRODUTOS  WHERE FILIAL = @NOME_FILIAL AND DATA_AJUSTE IS NOT NULL GROUP BY DATA_AJUSTE)

UPDATE ESTOQUE_PRODUTOS SET DATA_AJUSTE = '20190101' WHERE FILIAL = @NOME_FILIAL AND DATA_AJUSTE IS NOT NULL

GO

DELETE FROM LJ_ETL_REPOSITORIO WHERE ID_ETL_TIPO='171' AND FILTRO LIKE %@NOME_FILIAL%
```

Não consigo usar a variável com o like:

```
DELETE FROM LJ_ETL_REPOSITORIO WHERE ID_ETL_TIPO='171'
AND FILTRO LIKE %@NOME_FILIAL%
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente fazer assim:

```
DELETE FROM LJ_ETL_REPOSITORIO WHERE ID_ETL_TIPO='171' AND FILTRO LIKE '%' + @NOME_FILIAL + '%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar um query dinâmica, conforme o exemplo abaixo

```
EXEC(N'DELETE FROM LJ_ETL_REPOSITORIO WHERE ID_ETL_TIPO=''171'' AND FILTRO LIKE ''%' + @NOME_FILIAL + '%''')
```